# How to reference self as a model with django-ajax-related-fields

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to use django-ajax-related-fields, and the foreignkey field I'm trying to create a relation to is the model itself.  I've tried 'self', Node, and even self (no quotes), with the same results.

This is approximately how I'm trying to use it:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKeyByLetter('self', field_name = "name")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
```

I'm really a bit lost on how to use this in the first place, and the docs aren't terribly helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [ForeignKeyByLetter](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/#4.6%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0) is a form field not a model field, which explains why it's not working for you.

I'm not familiar with *django-ajax-related-fields* either, but from the looks of it, you'll want to try something along the lines of:

```
# in models.py
class Node(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('Node')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)


# in forms.py
from models import Node
from django.forms import ModelForm
from ajax_filtered_fields.forms import ForeignKeyByLetter

class NodeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Node
    parent = ForeignKeyByLetter(Node, field_name = "name")
```

Having not used it before, I may be wrong. Here's hoping this will at least put you on the right track.

Comment: You can also declare the field as `parent = ForeignKey('self')`. I prefer the explicit method that Shawn uses (it feels slightly more Pythonic), but I thought I would show this for completeness.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that.  You definitely got me on the right track.  Thanks.